# How To Write " max((a+b)/c) " in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to find the max value of "(a+b)/c", the example data:

```
{a:1,b:2,c:1}
{a:2,b:2,c:1}
{a:3,b:2,c:2}    
{a:4,b:2,c:2},
```

how to write the command ?

Comment: Your only hope is the aggregation framework. Here's the list of available commands: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this shoudl do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group:{
         _id:null,
         max:{
            $max:{
               $divide:[
                  {
                     $add:[
                        "$a",
                        "$b"
                     ]
                  },
                  "$c"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : null, "max" : 4 }
```

Comment: It's OK, Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You have to do an **aggregate** (see : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/
)

if your data collection is in myCollection, it should look something like that :

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
    'myMax': { '$max': { '$divide': [ {'$add': [ '$a', '$b' ] } , '$c' } }
}])
```

Comment: not able to test at the moment, maybe a pair of curly braces {} or some similar thing is missing here

Comment: ‘$group’ should be in instead of 'myMax' ?

Comment: there should be a "$group" containing everything, you're right, but also you need "name" (here : myMax) for the result. see @felix  's answer for the correct syntax :) .